# How do I keep my <h1> header to remain on top of my <h2> header?

Tags: html, css, header, position, alignment

I'm a beginner at web design and just tackled at designing my own website. I'm a graphic designer and designed a mock-up of what I want the site to look like. I got most of it done except for this part I got stuck on, getting my < h1 > header to remain on top of my < h2 > header.Both of these headers are on top of a video background playing in a loop. Right now they are side by side. I also wanted to add a horizontal line between the two headers - part of my design. Below are my HTML & CSS codes. [I also attached an image of my design vs what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wD98.jpg). Thank you in advance.

Also if anyone has any tips for me or know the best video tutorials that can help me, i'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

**The H1 & H2 are in the class=section under "Video Section".**

**CSS Code & HTML**

```css
@font-face{
 src: url(fonts/KeepCalm-Medium.ttf);
 font-family: keepcalm;}

@font-face{
 src: url(fonts/GOTHIC.TTF);
 font-family: centurygothic;}

body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;}


/**Video Section**/
.section {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100%;
 height: 534px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 overflow: hidden;}

.section h1 {
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center; 
 height: 108px;
 width:342px;
 font-family: keepcalm;
 font-size:36px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight:500;
 line-height: 60px;
 transform: scale(1.189,1.189);
 letter-spacing: 15px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 z-index: 1; }

.section span { font-size: 48px;}

hr {
 display: block;
 z-index: 1;}

.section h2{
 width: 181px;
 height: 22px;
 font-family: centurygothic;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size:35px;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 9px;
 z-index:2;
}

.video-container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;}

/*Topbar Section*/
.topbar {
 margin: 0px;
}
.topbar { 
 background-color: #e8e8e8;
 font-family: KeepCalm;
 font-size: 14px;
 align-items:flex-start;
 color: #000000;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 0px 0 0px 70px;}


.topbar > li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 20px 0 20px;}

.topbar > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;}

.phone {
 width:20px;
 padding: 4px 0 0px 4px }

.mail {
 height: 14px;
 }
/**Logo Section**/
.logo{
 float:left;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;}

/**Logo Text**/

.logotext {
 font-size: 14px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 140px;
 font-family: KeepCalm;
 float:left;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 }

.logotext span {
 font-size: 14px;
 display: block;
 line-height: 14px;
 font-family: CenturyGothic;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.logotext span span {
 font-size: 14px;
 display: inline;
 line-height: 14px;
 font-family: CenturyGothic;
 font-weight: 400;
 background:  #e8e8e8;
}
/*Navigation Responsive*/
.selector-for-some-widget {
 box-sizing: content-box;}
 
.nav-item {
 background-color: #fff;
 font-family: KeepCalm;
 font-size: 14px;
 align-items:flex-start;
 color: #000000;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 20px 0 20px 0px;}

.nav-item  {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 20px 0 20px;}

.nav-item {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
 color:  #e8e8e8;}

/*Topbar & Navigation Responsive*/

@media (max-width: 768px){
 .logo{
 width:5em; 
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 }
 
 .logotext {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 9pt;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-right: 100px;}
  
 .logotext span {
  line-height: 9pt;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  }
 .logotext span span {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  }
 .video-container {display: none;}
}

@media (max-width: 580px){
 .mail{width: 0px;}
 .hotmail{font-size: 0px;}
 .video-container {display: none;}
}

@media (max-width: 350px){
 .topbar {font-size: 0px;}
 .phone{ width:0px;}
 .mail {display: 0px;}
 .logotext { font-size: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="testtry.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>testtry</title> 
</head>
<body>

<!--Topbar-->

<div class="topbar">
 <ul class="topbar">
 <img src="Images/phone.png" alt="Call me at" class="phone">
 <li class="topbar topbartext">416-948-2164</li>
 <img src="mail1.png" alt="Email me at" class="mail">
 <li class="hotmail"><a href="">micaela-butron@hotmail.ca</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!--Navbar Responsive-->

<div class="Navcontainer">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a href="#"><img src="Logo1.png" alt="Micaela Butron Logo" class="logo"></a>
     <h1 class="logotext">
     I'm Micaela Butron.
     <span>an <span>Urban Designer</span>, + Graphic Designer.</span>
   </h1>
 
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Resume</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
    </div>
 </nav>
</div>


<!--VideoSection-->

<div class="section">
 <h1>Micaela <span>Butron</span></h1>
 <h2>Designer</h2>

 <div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="Images/Videos/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
 </div>
</div>

<!--Bootstrap Javascript Link-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="testtry.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>testtry</title>  
</head>
<body>

<!--Topbar-->

<div class="topbar">
    <ul class="topbar">
    <img src="Images/phone.png" alt="Call me at" class="phone">
    <li class="topbar topbartext">416-948-2164</li>
    <img src="mail1.png" alt="Email me at" class="mail">
    <li class="hotmail"><a href="">micaela-butron@hotmail.ca</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!--Navbar Responsive-->

<div class="Navcontainer">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <a href="#"><img src="Logo1.png" alt="Micaela Butron Logo" class="logo"></a>
            <h1 class="logotext">
                    I'm Micaela Butron.
                    <span>an <span>Urban Designer</span>, + Graphic Designer.</span>
            </h1>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Resume</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </nav>
</div>


<!--VideoSection-->

<div class="section">
  <div>
        <h1>Micaela <span>Butron</span></h1>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <span class="line"></span>

    <h2>Designer</h2>


    <div class="video-container">
        <video autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="Images/Videos/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Bootstrap Javascript Link-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
     @font-face{
    src: url(fonts/KeepCalm-Medium.ttf);
    font-family: keepcalm;}

    @font-face{
        src: url(fonts/GOTHIC.TTF);
        font-family: centurygothic;}

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;}

    hr{
      border-top-color: black;
    }
    /**Video Section**/
    .section {
        position: relative;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        width: 100%;
        height: 534px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .section h1 {
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;    
        height: 108px;
        width:342px;
        font-family: keepcalm;
        font-size:36px;
        color: #000;
        font-weight:500;
        line-height: 60px;
        transform: scale(1.189,1.189);
        letter-spacing: 15px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
      display: block;
      padding-bottom: 150px;
    }
    hr{
      border-top: 1px solid red !important;  
    }


    .section span { font-size: 48px;}

    /* hr {
        display: block;
        z-index: 1;} */

    .section h2{
        width: 181px;
        height: 22px;
        font-family: centurygothic;
        color: #000;
        font-size:35px;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 9px;
        z-index:2;
      display: block;
    }

    .video-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;}

    /*Topbar Section*/
    .topbar {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .topbar { 
        background-color: #e8e8e8;
        font-family: KeepCalm;
        font-size: 14px;
        align-items:flex-start;
        color: #000000;
        list-style: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0px 0 0px 70px;}


    .topbar > li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 20px 0 20px;}

    .topbar > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;}

    .phone {
        width:20px;
        padding: 4px 0 0px 4px }

    .mail {
        height: 14px;
        }
    /**Logo Section**/
    .logo{
        float:left;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 20px;}

    /**Logo Text**/

    .logotext {
        font-size: 14px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 140px;
        font-family: KeepCalm;
        float:left;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

    .logotext span {
        font-size: 14px;
        display: block;
        line-height: 14px;
        font-family: CenturyGothic;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .logotext span span {
        font-size: 14px;
        display: inline;
        line-height: 14px;
        font-family: CenturyGothic;
        font-weight: 400;
        background:  #e8e8e8;
    }
    /*Navigation Responsive*/
    .selector-for-some-widget {
        box-sizing: content-box;}

    .nav-item {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: KeepCalm;
        font-size: 14px;
        align-items:flex-start;
        color: #000000;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 20px 0 20px 0px;}

    .nav-item  {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 20px 0 20px;}

    .nav-item {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;}

    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
        color:  #e8e8e8;}

    /*Topbar & Navigation Responsive*/

    @media (max-width: 768px){
        .logo{
        width:5em;  
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        }

        .logotext {
            font-size: 0.7em;
            line-height: 9pt;
            padding-bottom: 1px;
            padding-right: 100px;}

        .logotext span {
            line-height: 9pt;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            }
        .logotext span span {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 1em;
            }
        .video-container {display: none;}
    }

    @media (max-width: 580px){
        .mail{width: 0px;}
        .hotmail{font-size: 0px;}
        .video-container {display: none;}
    }

    @media (max-width: 350px){``
        .topbar {font-size: 0px;}
        .phone{ width:0px;}
        .mail {display: 0px;}
        .logotext { font-size: 0px;}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! can't believe a simple < div > between them & some padding is what did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kara2lucy112/4whn91b5/34/#&togetherjs=0INK0h4PoC

i.e.

```
    .wrapper{
     text-align:center; 
    }
    <div class="section">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Michaela Burton</h1><h2> Designer</h2> </div>
    Section continues blah blah blah 
    </div>
```

The H1 and H2 need to be wrapped in another div that will apply the centering styles. As shown above

Comment: I didn't think that would happen unless there was a float on the <h1> element. Don't block-level elements always push other block level elements down, absent a float setting?

Comment: I followed these steps but it just changed to this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yar5F.jpg both headers are still next to each other, just not center-aligned anymore.

Comment: Let me relook at this. I was skimming quickly, my fault.

Comment: Okay so I see where the  issue is now. You need to wrap the titles in a div and then apply the combined styling to that. I knew it was something along those lines, Give them the 100% widths, and then wrap them in a div that contains the text align and justify content properties. Sorry about that, this is what I get for jumping the gun.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your CSS file. It's for screen widths 991px and below.

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
    .section {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .section h1 {
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .section h1:after {
        content: '';
        background-color: #FFF;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 150px;
        height: 10px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .section h2 {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```